register_sidebar has a bool param show_in_rest what are the repercussions of enabling it?
register_sidebar has a bool parameter show_in_rest. By default this is False. Setting it to true adds (I think 5) REST API paths.
I am trying to understand what this could be good for. Specifically, what are the repercussions of enabling it and what the intended use might be?
Can you explain this to me or point me to documentation that would help me understand when I might want to use this option?

look this file https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.6.2/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-sidebars-controller.php these endpoints allow to get details about sidebars and to edit them and their widgets.
